# TSQL Updating a record within a select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssrs-2012

When retrieving a data set via a select statement, I want to update existing records based on the vales in columns for each retrieved record.  I can't use a function to update a record and I can't use a stored procedure in a select statement.  I also fount that I cannot circumvent these restrictions by executing a stored procedure from a function.

Any ideas?  Following is my current code with a comment where I feel I need to call something that will update the record.  This code will be used in SSRS so one solution might be to execute a stored procedure inside the reports custom code but I cant get that to work either.

```
select sw.SMACTVSEQ as JDE_ActiveRec 
    ,sw.SMCSSEQ as JDE_SalesSeq
    ,bu.MCRP04 as JDE_DivID
    ,sw.SMHBMCUS as JDE_CommID
    ,cm.CMDL01 as JDE_CommunityName
    ,rtrim(sw.SMMCU) as JDE_LotID
    ,sw.SMBYR as JDE_BuyerABNo
    ,JDE_SSID = case
        When ab.ABURRF is null then cast(0 as int)
        When ab.ABURRF = '' then cast(0 as int)
        else cast(ab.ABURRF as int)
        end
    ,ss.Customer_ID as SS_CustID
    ,ss.Lot_ID as SS_LotID
    ,ss.Customer_Status as SS_CustStatus
    ,[dbo].[udf_ConvertJDEdate](sw.SMCDJ) as JDE_DateClosed
    ,case when ab.ABURRF >0 then 'Manually Update'
        else
            case when @Update_Mode ='Yes' then
            'Yes/Error' 
            /* **************
               Replace 'Yes/Error' with procedure to update  
               JDE_F0101_ABURRF and return 'Yes' or 'Error'
               ************** */
            else @Update_Mode
            end
        end as Update_Mode
    from [dbo].[crp_F44H501] sw
        left outer join [dbo].[crp_F44H101] cm 
            on cm.[CMHBMCUS]=sw.smhbmcus and cm.[CMCPHASE]=sw.[SMCPHASE] 
        left outer join [dbo].[crp_F0006] bu
            on bu.mcmcu = sw.smmcu 
        left outer join [dbo].[stg_F0101] ab
            on ab.aban8 = sw.SMBYR
        left outer join (
            select distinct(lot_id)
                ,customer_ID
                ,customer_status
            from [dbo].[SS_FactDemographic]
                        ) ss
            on ltrim(ss.lot_id) = ltrim(sw.SMMCU)

    Where sw.smactvseq='1' 
        and sw.SMBYR > 0
        and ab.ABURRF <> ss.Customer_ID
        and ss.Customer_Status = 'Buyer'
        and (bu.MCRP04 = @Division_ID or @Division_ID ='All')
        and (ltrim(sw.SMHBMCUS) = @Community_ID or @Community_ID ='All')
    Order by JDE_DivID,JDE_CommID,JDE_LotID
```

Comment: a select is a select. an update is an update. seems like you eant to call a strored proc to do both....

Comment: You can't mix different types of statements in the same statement. You can't update in a select, or delete in an insert, or anything like that.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  They just confirm what I already knew.  I was just hoping to find a way to update when the record is retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

Put the UPDATE query in the TSQL of the report query **before your data query**. As long as your query is valid and you have permission, SSRS will run TSQL to UPDATE data, use TEMP tables, etc. The SSRS Query Editor may not like everything that you can do so you might need to make your query in SSMS (which I usually do anyways).

I think your query would look something like:

```
UPDATE sw
SET Update_Mode = CASE WHEN ab.ABURRF >0 THEN 'Manually Update'
                        ELSE CASE WHEN @Update_Mode ='Yes' THEN 'Yes/Error' ELSE @Update_Mode END
                        END
FROM [dbo].[crp_F44H501] sw  
INNER JOIN [dbo].[stg_F0101] ab on ab.aban8 = sw.SMBYR


select sw.SMACTVSEQ as JDE_ActiveRec 
    ,sw.SMCSSEQ as JDE_SalesSeq
    ,bu.MCRP04 as JDE_DivID
    ,sw.SMHBMCUS as JDE_CommID
    ,cm.CMDL01 as JDE_CommunityName
    ,rtrim(sw.SMMCU) as JDE_LotID
    ,sw.SMBYR as JDE_BuyerABNo
    ,JDE_SSID = case
        When ab.ABURRF is null then cast(0 as int)
        When ab.ABURRF = '' then cast(0 as int)
        else cast(ab.ABURRF as int)
        end
    ,ss.Customer_ID as SS_CustID
    ,ss.Lot_ID as SS_LotID
    ,ss.Customer_Status as SS_CustStatus
    ,[dbo].[udf_ConvertJDEdate](sw.SMCDJ) as JDE_DateClosed
    ,sw.Update_Mode
    from [dbo].[crp_F44H501] sw
        left outer join [dbo].[crp_F44H101] cm 
            on cm.[CMHBMCUS]=sw.smhbmcus and cm.[CMCPHASE]=sw.[SMCPHASE] 
        left outer join [dbo].[crp_F0006] bu
            on bu.mcmcu = sw.smmcu 
        left outer join [dbo].[stg_F0101] ab
            on ab.aban8 = sw.SMBYR
        left outer join (
            select distinct(lot_id)
                ,customer_ID
                ,customer_status
            from [dbo].[SS_FactDemographic]
                        ) ss
            on ltrim(ss.lot_id) = ltrim(sw.SMMCU)
    Where sw.smactvseq='1' 
        and sw.SMBYR > 0
        and ab.ABURRF <> ss.Customer_ID
        and ss.Customer_Status = 'Buyer'
        and (bu.MCRP04 = @Division_ID or @Division_ID ='All')
        and (ltrim(sw.SMHBMCUS) = @Community_ID or @Community_ID ='All')
    Order by JDE_DivID,JDE_CommID,JDE_LotID
```

Comment: This is the way I would do it. I'm still surprised how many people are under the impression tat SSRS can only do single SELECT statements.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately ab.ABURRF is a variable that changes with each selected record and would be unknown prior to the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you:

```
    update X set Update_Mode =  case when X.ABURRF      >   0   then 'Manually Update'  else
                                case when @Update_Mode  =   ''  then 'Yes/Error'        else    @Update_Mode
                                end
                                end
    from
    (
    select
        sw.SMACTVSEQ        as  JDE_ActiveRec 
    ,   sw.SMCSSEQ          as  JDE_SalesSeq
    ,   bu.MCRP04           as  JDE_DivID
    ,   sw.SMHBMCUS         as  JDE_CommID
    ,   cm.CMDL01           as  JDE_CommunityName
    ,   rtrim(sw.SMMCU)     as  JDE_LotID
    ,   sw.SMBYR            as  JDE_BuyerABNo
    ,   JDE_SSID            =   case
                                When ab.ABURRF is null  then cast(0 as int)
                                When ab.ABURRF = ''     then cast(0 as int)
                                else                    cast(ab.ABURRF as int)
                                end
    ,   ss.Customer_ID as SS_CustID
    ,   ss.Lot_ID as SS_LotID
    ,   ss.Customer_Status as SS_CustStatus
    ,   [dbo].[udf_ConvertJDEdate](sw.SMCDJ) as JDE_DateClosed
    ,   ab.ABURRF
    ,   ''                  as  Update_Mode
    --, case when ab.ABURRF >0 then 'Manually Update'
    --    else
    --        case when @Update_Mode ='Yes' then
    --        'Yes/Error' 
    --        /* **************
    --            Replace 'Yes/Error' with procedure to update  
    --            JDE_F0101_ABURRF and return 'Yes' or 'Error'
    --            ************** */
    --        else @Update_Mode
    --        end
    --    end as Update_Mode
    from            [dbo].[crp_F44H501] sw
    left outer join [dbo].[crp_F44H101] cm on cm.[CMHBMCUS]=sw.smhbmcus and cm.[CMCPHASE]=sw.[SMCPHASE] 
    left outer join [dbo].[crp_F0006] bu    on bu.mcmcu = sw.smmcu 
    left outer join [dbo].[stg_F0101] ab    on ab.aban8 = sw.SMBYR
    left outer join (select distinct(lot_id),customer_ID,customer_status from [dbo].[SS_FactDemographic]) ss  on ltrim(ss.lot_id) = ltrim(sw.SMMCU)

    Where   sw.smactvseq='1' 
    and     sw.SMBYR > 0
    and     ab.ABURRF <> ss.Customer_ID
    and     ss.Customer_Status = 'Buyer'
    and     (bu.MCRP04 = @Division_ID or @Division_ID ='All')
    and     (ltrim(sw.SMHBMCUS) = @Community_ID or @Community_ID ='All')
    )   X

    --Order by  JDE_DivID
    --,         JDE_CommID
    --,         JDE_LotID
```

Remember, the `@Update_Mode` variable has to be declared before running this update, else you will get an error.